# Showing $Kf$ is a compact operator on $L^p(\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence, compact-operators

> Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, $1<p<\infty$, and $1/p+1/q=1$. If $k: X\times X\to\mathbb{F}$ is an $\mathcal{S}\times\mathcal{S}$ measurable function such that
> \begin{align*}
>     \sup\bigg\{\int_X|k(x, y)|^q\,d\mu(y):\,x\in X\bigg\}<\infty,
> \end{align*}
> then
> \begin{align*}
>     (Kf)(x)=\int_X k(x, y)f(y)\,d\mu(y)
> \end{align*}
> defines a compact operator on $L^p(\mu)$.

I have seen the proof of this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914588/integral-operator-on-lp-is-compact?noredirect=1&lq=1) but my hypothesis is a little different and my background in topology is pretty weak. I would like to show that $Kf$ is completely continuous so that I can use the result that any completely continuous operator on a reflexive space is compact. I am wondering if someone wouldn't mind taking a "heres why $Kf$ is completely continuous for dummies" approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$c= \sup\bigg\{\int_X|k(x, y)|^q\,d\mu(y):\,x\in X\bigg\}.$$
Suppose that $f_n\to0$ weakly. This means that for every $g\in L^q$,
$$
\int_X f_n\overline g\,d\mu\to0. 
$$
In particular, for each $x$
$$
\int_Xk(x,y)\,f_n(y)\,d\mu(y)\to0
$$
Since a [weakly convergent sequence is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/825790/22857), there exists $b>0$ with $\|f_n\|_p<b$ for all $n$. Then, by Hölder,
$$
\bigg|\int_Xk(x,y)\,f_n(y)\,d\mu(y)\bigg|\leq\Bigg(\int_X|k(x,y)|^q\,d\mu(y)\bigg)^{1/q}\|f_n\|_p<bc^{1/q}.
$$
Because we are in a finite-measure space, a bounded function is integrable. Then, using Dominated Covergence,
\begin{align}
\|Kf_n\|_p^p&=\int_X\bigg|\int_X k(x,y)\,f_n(y)\,d\mu(y)\bigg|^p\,d\mu(x)\to0.
\end{align}
so $K$ is completely continuous, and as $L^p$ is reflexive, $K$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredibly helpful!

Comment: Nice to hear :)